# How can I invoke events asynchronously and sequentially?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, asynchronous, threadpool

I've the following class:

```
class Integration
{
    public event EventHandler<LogEventArgs> LogMessageEvent  

    protected virtual void OnLog(LogEventArgs e)
    {
         if(LogMessageEvent != null)
             LogMessageEvent(this, e);
    }

    public void SomeWork()
    { 
        //Do some things...

        var e = new LogMessageEvent("The file was copied...");
        OnLog(e);

        //Do more things...

        var e = new LogMessageEvent("Another thing...");
        OnLog(e);
    }
}
```

I need that event subscribers do not block the SomeWork method and that the execution be sequential ("The file was copied..." event execute always first)

I tried with tasks:

```
Task.Run(... OnLog())....
```

But the problem is that sometimes a task created **later** raises an event **before** a previously created task. (As expected, considering that I'm not doing synchronization.)

I'm suspecting that there is some easiest way to accomplish this task (Call events sequentially and asynchronously ).

Comment: something like `private object _syncRoot = new object();`  -> `public void SomeWork() { lock(_syncRoot){ /* Do some things... */ } }`?

Comment: How attached are you to the `event` model? Because that forces you to keep it internal to `Integration`. An external Queue might be better.

Comment: Basic problem here is that the class tries to do too much.

Comment: Hi @HenkHolterman! I don't think so, can you explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your last used `Task`-object and use [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd270696(v=vs.110).aspx).

It tells your task to continue with the new event-invocation when the first task has finished. So the event are not triggered in parallel but sequentially.

`ContinueWith` returns a new `Task`-object, so you need to update your reference, so the next `ContinueWith`-call can be successful.

This is not thread-safe but as long as you call it only from one thread it should work (and did perfectly for me).

Comment: That's exactly what I did. But I thought I was reinventing the wheel . Thank you!

Comment: IMHO, that is the purpose of `ContinueWith`.